# How to randomize the percentage values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a problem with VBA excel.

In column F, I have a number 57.07%. This column has 102 Rows. The idea is to generate random values in percentage, but the total average of these random numbers has to be 57.07%

I managed to generate random full numbers. But when it comes to adding and removing decimals for some reason I get no results.

```
Sub RandomiseSum()
    Dim countries As Range, country As Range, pageviews As Range, clicks As Range, impressions As Range, col_f As Range, col_g As Range, col_h As Range, earnings As Range



Dim arr() As Double, i, z, y As Integer

'~~>Count the result of the range of countries
Set countries = Range("B4:B102")
Set pageviews = Range("C4:C102")
Set impressions = Range("D4:D102")
Set clicks = Range("E4:E102")
Set col_f = Range("F4:F102")
Set col_g = Range("G4:G102")
Set col_h = Range("H4:H102")
Set earnings = Range("I4:I102")
ReDim arr(countries.count - 1)
For i = 0 To countries.count - 1
    arr(i) = Rnd
Next i
i = i - 1                                           '~~> Remove 1 from the total cell number in order to put the decimals/diferences in it at the end

'~~> Totals
TotalC = Range("C2").Value
TotalD = Range("D2").Value
TotalE = Range("E2").Value
avg_f = Range("F2").Value
avg_g = Range("G2").Value
avg_h = Range("H2").Value
TotalI = Range("I2").Value


col_h = avg_h
half1 = i / 2
half2 = (i / 2) + 1
z = half2
y = 4
x = 0

Do Until x = half1
    this_nr = "H" & y
    xnum = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 42) / 100
    Range(this_nr).Value = Range(this_nr).Value - xnum
     
    y = y + 1
    z_nr = "H" & z
    Range(z_nr).Value = Range(z_nr).Value + xnum
    
    z = z + 1
    x = x + 1
Loop
rnr = 0
Do Until rnr = half1
    x12 = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(4, 102)
    x22 = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(4, 102)
    x12 = "H" & x12
    x22 = "H" & x22
    x3 = x12
    
    Range(x12).Value = Range(x22).Value
    Range(x22).Value = Range(x3).Value

    rnr = rnr + 1
    Loop
        y = 4
        z = half2
        For x = 0 To x = half1
            this_nr = "H" & y
            z_nr = "H" & z
      
           Range(this_nr).Value = Range(this_nr).Value - 0.3
           Range(z_nr).Value = Range(z_nr).Value + 0.03
            
            z = z + 1
            x = x + 1
         Next x
End Sub
```

As you can see from the picture, I get that .07 in all cells but I'm not being able to remove that value from some cells and add it to other ones.

[image: IMG:]

Any ideas?
Is my loop wrong?

Comment: col_h = Range of the column H4:H102
avg_h = 57.07%
i = Row count

Comment: The upper part of your code is missing. Can you edit your post and add it?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio
I just did. It's no the full code but only the code for Column H
you can just assign the value 57.07%   /   0.5707  to avg_h

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it. If anyone else will encounter the same problem, here's the code.
What I did here is that I added another variable named "xnum2" where I would generate a random decimal number and then for each loop I would remove that value from the CELLx.value and add it to another CELLy.value, so that the average would still be the same.

```
    col_h = avg_h
    half1 = i / 2
    half2 = (i / 2) + 1
    z = half2
    y = 4
    x = 0
    
    Do Until x = half1
        this_nr = "H" & y
        xnum = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 42) / 100
        Range(this_nr).Value = Range(this_nr).Value - xnum
        
      xnum2 = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 9) / 10000
   Range(this_nr).Value = Range(this_nr).Value - xnum2
        
        y = y + 1
        z_nr = "H" & z
        Range(z_nr).Value = Range(z_nr).Value + xnum
      Range(z_nr).Value = Range(z_nr).Value + xnum2
        
        z = z + 1
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    rnr = 0
    Do Until rnr = half1
        x12 = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(4, 102)
        x22 = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(4, 102)
        x12 = "H" & x12
        x22 = "H" & x22
        x3 = x12
        
        Range(x12).Value = Range(x22).Value
        Range(x22).Value = Range(x3).Value
    
        rnr = rnr + 1
        Loop
```

Comment: I think you should state what was wrong with the previous code (at least what part of the code was the issue).

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I just did.
Since you're here and you're looking at the code, could you please enlighten me on how I could mane the range of the column more dynamic.
As you can see here:
Set col_h = Range("H4:H102")

I'm declaring a fixed range. 
How would I do it so it would start at H4 until "Last_cell -1"

Comment: to get the last row, declare a variable that will hold the value: Dim lRow as long. Then use  lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row